# Modifying objects within Angular Scope inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm creating a form in HTML using ng-repeat to generate the form elements from an object in the scope.  I also use that object to generate other elements outside of the ng-repeat.

A simplified example looks like this in HTML:

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div class="block1">
          <form ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
              <label>{{key}}</label>
              <input ng-model="value" />
              <p>{{value}}</p>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="block2">
        <p>
          {{test.a}}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{test.b}}
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this in JS:

```
angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = {
        a:"abc",
        b:"def"
    }
}
```

In this example, the text in block2 is set to the initial values of `test.a` and `test.b`.  The input values and `<p>` values inside of the loop are also set to the initial value.

When I modify the values within the inputs, the `<p>` values inside of the ng-repeat block update correctly, but the `<p>` tags in block2 fail to update.

Why is this the behavior?  Does ng-repeat create its own isolated scope?  If so how can I get the controller level scope to update?  Also, could somebody explain the thinking behind this  behavior and any advantages it provides?

[JSFiddle Showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/HB5fJ/1/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each repeated item. As a result you are trying to pass a primitive to child scope which won't create a reference to parent. When you pass objects however, you pass the original object reference.

**From the mouth of one of the fathers of Angular:**

> **Always have a dot in ng-model**

[**This is a great video regarding Angular Best Practices**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) given by Angular creator (2012/12/11). Go to minute 31 for well explained detail of this exact situation

Modify data to array of objects:

```
$scope.test = [{ val:"abc",key:'a'}, {val:"def",key:'b'} ]
```

Then in repeater:

```
<form ng-repeat="item in test">
  <label>{{item.key}}</label>
  <input ng-model="item.val" />
  <p>{{item.val}}</p>
</form>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ymzbgHMdsOEkxmRjPBkG?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of the behavior.  My use case requires that I reference the properties of "test" by name in the outer scope, so an array doesn't work for me, but sub objects seem to work fine.

Comment: My Object keys are UNIX times, so this is very difficult for me

Comment: @neaumusic comment not clear, post a question if you need help

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = [
        {label:"a", value:"abc"},
        {label:"b", value:"def"}
    ]
}
```

and

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div class="block1">
          <form ng-repeat="o in test">
              <label>{{o.label}}</label>
              <input ng-model="o.value" />
              <p>{{o.value}}</p>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="block2">
        <p>
          {{test[0].value}}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{test[1].value}}
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angularjs uses the fact that objects are passed by reference. So, if you pass a object to a function and change the object inside the function, the object outside also changes.
Look at this updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB5fJ/5/)