# ng-repeat displays model but not updating it

Tags: angularjs, binding, directive

I have a directive:

```
<button ng-click="update()">Update channels for {{id}}</button><br/>  
<li ng-repeat="(k,v) in entries">
    {{k}} is {{v}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="v"></input>
</li>


controller: ($scope, $resource) ->
    Query = $resource('/dmx/getdefs/:id')

    Query.get {id: $scope.id}, (res) ->
       $scope.entries = res
       return
```

It retrieves the data from the server and display them. No problem here. 
I edit one value.
However, when I click on update, I can see in my handler that $scope.entries has NOT changed.

Why ?

I'm able to fix this:
- Rather than server returns a dictionnay {'red': 200, 'blue': 100} instead I return an array
[ {'key' : 'red', 'val': 200}, {'key': blue, 'val': 100}].

If I change the directive to:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in entries">
   {{item.key}} has {{item.val}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.val"></input>
</li>
```

it works fine. But is there a way without an array ? Seems Angular is able to display a dictionnary with ng-repeat but not able to do databinding both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array way seems to be the right way of doing it. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589581/2759075).

If you insist on iterating through your original object, you can change your HTML to something like:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in entries">
        {{k}} is {{v}}
       <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.entries[k]"></input>
   </li>
```

`$parent` is used since `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each instance of the repeated element.

Answer (score 1):

Each repeated element is getting it's own scope so you need to do something like this to reference the entries object:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="entries[k]"></input>
```