# ng-model binding not updates another ng-model on the same object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code

http://plnkr.co/edit/aycnNVoD96UMbsC7rFmg?p=preview

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="names=['One']">

<input type="text" ng-model="names[0]">

  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name"> {{ name }}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

When i change value of name[0] in the first input box it changes values of the second input box.
But when i change value of name[0] in the second input box it does not change value of the first input box. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `ng-repeat` creating a child scope, so the reference to name inside the `ng-repeat` is different to that original one in the names array, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> New AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat,
>   ng-switch, ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the
>   problem often shows up when these directives are involved. (See this
>   example for a quick illustration of the problem.)

Regarding as to why this happens, when you bind the input to name in names inside the `ng-repeat`, you are creating a new property on the new child scope created by the `ng-repeat` called `name`, and thus the `ng-model` of the textbox created by the ng-repeat is referencing a different name to that of the actual 0th element of the names array. As others have pointed out, if you use `names[$index]` you are *implicitly* referencing the 0th element of the `names` array, thus **NOT** creating a new name property on the child scope created by the `ng-repeat`. An angular best practice is not to have ng-models bound to primitives, rather objects, Sandy has mentioned in his answer if you bind to an object you will overcome this, and the 2 other posters have answered this by using `$index` to refer to the 0th element of the names array. This is one of [the nucances of scope inheritance in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/189756).

A couple more handy links:

[Here](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589417/modifying-objects-within-angular-scope-inside-ng-repeat).

Comment: @Hoto and I've added an explanation on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you bind your second input to : names[$index]

`<input type="text" ng-model="names[$index]"> {{ name }}`

Answer (score 1):

> You need **to provide** `$index` in your ng-model.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" ng-model="names[$index]"> {{ name }}
</li>
```

You are binding `ng-model="names[0]"`. So it means that you are binding value on first index of `names` array.

So when we write `ng-model="names[$index]"` in `ng-repeat` it means that all values will be bound accordingly into array. `$index` is an iterator offset of the repeated element.

```
names[0] = 'One'
names[1] = 'Two'
```

and so on!

Comment: You made a typo in your code, you need to bind it to names[$index] and not name[$index]

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give my bit on this. Somewhat related to your problem as I see.

```
<body>
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="names=[{value:'One'}, {value:'Two'}]">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name.value"> {{ name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Instead of binding the array item directly to the control, I would prefer to create an object of the array and then bind value of each item. This way we can avoid reference problems.

A working prototype [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsalands/wrky2nLb/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Per your request, I've added additional detauils to my answer addressing why the solution proposed by you and the other 2 posters relate to my answer.

Comment: Oops...failed to express myself. I meant your approach was better on not discussing about fix but rather giving explanation. Inspired by your answer, I gave explanation :D